# How do you convert JQuery event target to a wrapped set?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my recent project, I am using the click event like so:

```
$(".nav-item").click(function(evt){
    do something here...
})
```

Inside the event handler function, I want to look at the children of the event target using jQuery selectors. Something like

```
$(event.target + " > .subitem").html()
```

assuming .subitem was a childnode with a class subitem.

This doesnt seem to work. Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: `$(" > .subitem", evt.target).html()`

The second parameter to the [jQuery function](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext) provides context to the first parameter.

Please note that `evt.target` will be the actual element clicked; if you just want the specific `.nav-item` that was clicked, use `$(this)`.

Comment: Just some additional info for Arpit: The 'event.target' part is jQuery object, not a string. You are trying to concatenate an object with a string which definitely won't work.